# Why takes bulk insert in elasticsearch much more time with linestrings than with polygons?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, geometry, geojson

my index mapping for the location field is:

```
{
    "type": "geo_shape",
    "tree": "quadtree",
    "precision": "25m"
}
```

There are only two other fields with almost no content.

bulk inserting polygons and points works alright, not well, but (50.000 points = 3 Minutes; 450 polygons = 1.5 Minutes). But as soon as I try to insert linestrings I run into timeouts. I tried less precision and and more time, what of course helps a bit but in the end even 20 minutes and 50m precision ran into a timeout with a linestring consisting of 1500 points. The funny thing is most of the lines are actually also part of the polygons inserted before. All of it is valid geoJson. I have no Idea where look next. Does someone have a hint?